# How to install requests module in Python 3.4, instead of 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  I want to install the 'requests' module so it is accessible from Py3.4.

When I issued `pip install requests` on my terminal cmd line I got back:

> "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

How can I direct pip to install requests for 3.4 even though it is already in 2.7?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can [specify a Python version for `pip` to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions):

```
pip3.4 install requests
```

Python 3.4 has [pip support built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/), so you can also use:

```
python3.4 -m pip install
```

If you're running Ubuntu (or probably Debian as well), you'll need to install the system `pip3` separately:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This will install the `pip3` executable, so you can use it, as well as the earlier mentioned `python3.4 -m pip`:

```
pip3 install requests
```

Comment: Thanks but it errors out on me:  "pip3.4: command not found"      after entering "pip3.4 install requests"   <br/>  Also tried "pip 3.4" and "pip-3.4" but got same error msg

Comment: Try `python3.4 -m pip install requests`.

Comment: curious.  Tried that and got "/usr/bin/python3.4: No module named pip
"

Comment: I spun up a 14.04 VM and double checked that installing the python3-pip package first will make things work for you.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows with Python v3.6.5

```
py -m pip install requests
```

Answer (score 6):

Just answering this old thread can be installed without pip 
On windows or Linux:

1) Download Requests from https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests click on clone or download button

2) Unzip the files in your python directory .Exp your python is installed in C:Python\Python.exe then unzip there

3) Depending on the Os run the following command:

- **Windows** use command cd to your python directory location then  setup.py install
- **Linux** command: python setup.py install

Thats it :)

Answer (score 2):

while installing python packages in a global environment is doable, it is a best practice to isolate the environment between projects (creating virtual environments). Otherwise, confusion between Python versions will arise, just like your problem.

The simplest method is to use `venv` library in the project directory:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Where the first `venv` is to call the `venv` package, and the second `venv` defines the virtual environment directory name.
Then activate the virtual environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Once the virtual environment has been activated, your `pip install ...` commands would not be interfered with any other Python version or pip version anymore.
For installing `requests`:

```
pip install requests
```

Another benefit of the virtual environment is to have a concise list of libraries needed for that specific project.

*note: commands only work on Linux and Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue in beautiful soup , I solved this issue by this command , your issue will also get rectified . 
You are unable to install requests in python 3.4 because your python libraries are not updated . 
use this command 
`apt-get install python3-requests`
Just run it will ask you to add 222 MB space in your hard disk , just press Y and wait for completing process, after ending up whole process . check your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i just reinstalled the pip and it works, but I still wanna know why it happened...

i used the `apt-get remove --purge python-pip` after I just `apt-get install pyhton-pip` and it works, but don't ask me why...