# I can't install a Python module via pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I need to install the module 'Request' but when I run the command 
pip3 install Request
it gives me back this error:

This is what I need to run the program:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import random
```

and this is what I get when I try to install Request module via pip3 in terminal:

```
Collecting Request
Installing collected packages: Request
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 178, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 414, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 920, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 448, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 428, in move_wheel_files
    assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: Request .dist-info directory not found
```

If I run 
`pip install Request` it tells me that requirements are already satisfied, but when I run the program it says that module Request is missing.

Comment: it should be python 3.7 curernt version, means first reinstall python, and dont run pip (its for python < 3) you must use pip3 then

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install [`urllib.request.Request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request). It has been part of Python since version 3.3. You might be thinking of [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org) which is something else that you do need to install if you want to use it.

Answer (score -1):

I cleaned my python installation 2 & 3 and reinstalled from zero. It seems like my folders were messed up and packages were searched for in the wrong path.

`apt-get remove python
apt-get install python`

Comment: Note, this depends on the OS. Removing `python` on Ubuntu 16.04 will break a lot of things.

Answer (score -2):

Use `apt-get install python3-requests` . That error appear cause all your python3.x libraries are not updated.

By the way, duplicated question, use search function: [How to install requests module in Python 3.4, instead of 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362600/how-to-install-requests-module-in-python-3-4-instead-of-2-7)

Comment: I've tried solutions from that question but didn't solve. By the way I've tried also your solution and it indeed installed the package, but when I run the code It always tells me that I missed the 'Request' module

Comment: for that "manual" solution you may need to specify `... python3.x ..` where x is the current sub-version of python you are using. So the module will be installed in the correct directory.